# how to access the dynamic object in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My Code:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 public manipulate: any ;
 ...
 this.results.forEach(result => {
   var index = result.date_value;
   if (!this.manipulate.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
     this.manipulate.{index} = [];
   }
   this.manupulate.{index}.push(result);
 });
}
```

Expected Result:

```
this.manupulate = {
  20171001 : [
     0: { resultset },
     ...
  ]
}
```

How to write the program. 
If I use **Array** the browser handed. the reason is a high range of the index value.

The below javascript code is run perfectly.

```
manupulate[20171001] = 
  [
     0: { resultset },
     ...
  ]
}
```

If I use typescript the browser handed.

```
this.manupulate[20171001] = 
  [
     0: { resultset },
     ...
  ]
}
```

Thanks for all.

Comment: try this : this.manupulate[index].push(result);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

use this.manupulate[index].push(result); instead of this.manupulate.{index}.push(result);

```
if (!this.manipulate.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
    this.manipulate[index] = [];
}
this.manupulate[index].push(result);
```

Comment: I tried but the system is handed due to index value is large input. Ex: 20171003 this is large value it's hand the browser. Please try below code:   **this.manupulate[20171003]=10;**

Comment: @BalasubramaniSamiyappan Are you initializing your object? `public manipulate: any = {}`

Comment: My Initialization mistake: **public manipulate: any = []** this is wrong.